# remove elements from a vector of string (with exact names and starts of the names)

Tags: r

I have a long character vector of protein names which I want to reduce.

I want to remove from the vector all entries that are == "5-FCL-like_protein" and all entries that start with "CBSS-"

For the first problem, I can just use %in%

```
remove <- c("5-FCL-like_protein")
vec[! vec %in% remove]
```

But how can I include the entries that start with "CBSS-" as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two conditions in your subset. The first one is very similar to your `%in%` except I use `==` instead just because of personal preference. If you have multiple strings you want to exclude you can go back to `%in%`. The second one uses `grepl` to match `"CBSS-"` at the beginning of the string.

```
vec <- c("Protein1","Protein2", "CBSS-Protein 2", "5-FCL-like_protein")
vec[!vec == "5-FCL-like_protein" & !grepl("^CBSS-", vec)]
#[1] "Protein1" "Protein2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or we can use this within `grep`

```
grep("^(CBSS|5-FCL-like_protein$)", vec, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
#[1] "Protein1" "Protein2"
```

#### data

```
vec <- c("Protein1","Protein2", "CBSS-Protein 2", "5-FCL-like_protein")
```